# access arrays with rapidJson (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, parsing, rapidjson

I am trying to parse a Json file with rapidJson (v 0.11) but I fail to do it with what seems to be a simple array. Here is the structure of my file :

```
[{"id": "my_id1","type":"my_type1"},
 {"id": "my_id2","type":"my_type2"},
 ...
]
```

It seems that rapidJson does not read that type of file starting with an array.. Is there a way to handle that ?

Here is a extract of the code I tried to use :

`FILE * pFile = fopen ("my_json.json" , "r");
    rapidjson::FileStream is(pFile);
    rapidjson::Document document;
    document.ParseStream<0>(is);`

and i am stuck right here because i am supposed to access to the elements by this syntax `value = document["key"]`, but I don't have any "key" at the first level...

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please reduce your code to the relevant part and post it here

Comment: Which version of rapidjson you use and how you are trying to parse json (code)?

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Remove the comma after the second colon in each line.

Comment: right sorry i edited it (but that does not solve the problem)

Comment: _"i am supposed to access to the elements by this syntax value = document["key"], but I don't have any "key" at the first level..."_ Um `document[0]`? How else do you typically access arrays??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have an array at the top level of your JSON file, you would simply access your document by providing an index into that array.

For example:

```
// access first element
rapidjson::Value & val = document[0];
```

Comment: Thx ! It might seems obvious but it didn't feel that way when i was searching...
For those who gets an error message on `document[0]`, you can use `document[0u]` to solve it.

Comment: In newer versions at [GitHub](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson), no need to use `0u`. Please try the latest version.